# Instalar laravel app numa subpasta num servidor partilhado

Tags: laravel, htaccess, apache, deploy

Olá,
Neste momento tenho uma aplicação laravel instalada no meu servidor partilhado, a aplciação está dentro de public_html, sendo que a pasta public está dentro de public_html (public_hmtl/public) e tenho o seguinte htaccess na raiz da pasta public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
</IfModule>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Pretendia agora instalar uma outra aplicação dentro de uma subpasta second_app dentro de public_html (public_html/second_app), já criei a pasta e adicionei um index em html apenas para teste e criei um subdomínio a apontar para essa pasta. No entanto ao tentar aceder pelo endereço second_app.dominio.com aparece-me "Internal Server Error" e se tentar aceder por [www.dominio.com/second_app](http://www.dominio.com/second_app) apenas me mostra a pagina inicial como se estivesse em [www.dominio.com](http://www.dominio.com)

Julgo que tenha de mudar alguam coisa ho .htaccess da pasta public_html mas não sei o que faltará.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Você tentou alterar a terceira linha para?:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ second_app/public/$1
```

Não consegui testar aqui, mas acredito que resolva.